# How to update a value using string_agg without using a function?

Tags: postgresql

I solved this problem with a function and I like my solution, but I want to know if there is a way to solve this problem without using functions. Here is the thing:

There are four tables that are relevant to this:

1. `entities`: entities of the system (tenants)
2. `members`: members of an entity
3. `member_sets`: sets of members
4. `members_and_sets`: table to join members and sets (many to many)

The `member_sets` table has a column named `bits` which is a binary representation of the set, so, for example, if an entity has 5 members and one specific set has the third member, the value of the `bits` column is `00100`, the entity has three special kinds of sets: universe, empty and unit, their binary repesentation is: `11111`, `00000` and `10000` respectively, assuming the unit set has the first member.

The challenge is keep this binary representation of the set up to date; Whenever one member is added to the entity, all binary representations must be updated. This is easy to do with a trigger and a function, my solution is this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION setbits(INTEGER) RETURNS VARBIT AS
$$SELECT STRING_AGG(belongs, '')::VARBIT AS setbits FROM (
  SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(members_and_sets.set_id, 0), 1)::text AS belongs
  FROM  members LEFT JOIN members_and_sets
  ON members.id=members_and_sets.member_id
  AND members_and_sets.set_id=$1
  GROUP BY members.id,members_and_sets.set_id
  ORDER BY members.id)
AS bitsring;$$
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

-- calling this function in a trigger after inserting a new member:

UPDATE member_sets ms
SET bits=setbits(ms.id)
WHERE ms.entity_id=NEW.entity_id;
```

Now my question is: Can I do this without using a function? I tried with CTE but apparently I'm to noob to accomplish this; I couldn't pass the `set_id` to the must inner query so my solution was to wrap the query in a function and pass the `set_id` as an argument to the function. Again, this solution works perfectly, I just want to know if there is no way I can do this without a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your function body is simply a `SELECT`, you should be able to replace the function call with a subquery:

```
UPDATE member_sets ms
SET bits= (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(belongs, '')::VARBIT AS setbits FROM (
    SELECT LEAST(COALESCE(members_and_sets.set_id, 0), 1)::text AS belongs
    FROM  members LEFT JOIN members_and_sets
    ON members.id=members_and_sets.member_id
    AND members_and_sets.set_id=ms.id
    GROUP BY members.id,members_and_sets.set_id
    ORDER BY members.id)
  AS bitsring
)
WHERE ms.entity_id=NEW.entity_id;
```

Comment: wow, that was easy! I just couldn't make it work without the function. didn't know it was that easy. Thank you very much!